# How to assign data to an array from http responce in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, http, httpresponse

I am trying to make an API call and trying to assign data to an array but the last index value of API response is assigned to every array index which leads to assign the same value to all indexes of an array. The response of API is good but the loop alteration did not assign each value to every array index.

```
 image = new images;


  this.http.get("http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/DesignerProject/GetAll? 
   UserID="+this.userid+"&MaxResultCount="+10000).subscribe( res => {
    this.data=res;

    for (var j in this.data.result.items.lenght){
      this.imagesdataarray.push(this.image);
      this.imagesdataarray[j].projecttitle=this.data.result.items[j].name;
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're only getting the "last" element is because you're pushing the *reference* to `this.image` and changing what that reference refers to.

So here's a solution for what you want to do here, but I will give it with the caveat that generally speaking:

- you don't want to turn an Observable into static data: it's better practice to leave it as an Observable and only subscribe to it with the async pipe in the template
- you don't want to put logic in the `subscribe` callback: it's better practice to use pipeable operators as it makes things more readable and easier to maintain.

That being said, here's your solution:

```js
this.http.get(url).subscribe(res => {
  this.imagesdataarray = res.result.items.map(item => ({ ...item, projecttitle: item.name }));
});
```

This maps every item in the result array to an object with a projecttitle corresponding to the name property, and then assigns the resulting array to `this.imagesdataarray`.

Just to be thorough, here's how I would go about it:

```js
this.imageArrayObservable$ = this.http.get(url).pipe(
  map(response => response.result.items.map(item => ({...item, projectTitle: name})))
);
```

Then, in the template which consumes the data:

```html
<div class="need-the-data-in-here" *ngIf="imageArrayObservable$ | async as images">
  <img *ngFor="let image of images" [src]="image.url">
<!-- example where each image has a url property -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, man for your help 1 more thing is how I suppose to push my object in an array

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The `map` function I used maps one array into a new array, so `this.imagesdataarray` is already an array. It basically runs a `forEach` over the whole array and pushes each mapped item into the target array.